# how to load foreign relationship laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am storing information on a 4-day class. The information is dates 1-4 and each date has an instructor associated with it as there can be different instructors on different days. Let's just talk about day_1 and instructor_day_1 for now. My models are as follows:

Course Model:

```
public function instructor()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Instructor');
  }
```

Instructor Model:

```
  public function course()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Course');
  }
```

When i go to the @show method in my controller, i find the correct course but when i try to load the view, i can't figure out how to access the foreign relation. Right now i'm trying:

```
<p class="card-text">{{$course->day_1}} assigned to {{$course->instructor_day_1->instructor->name}}</p>
```

But that's not yielding anything but errors. If i do {{$course->instructor_day_1}}, i get the correct value from the database.

Is my relationship backwards? Does Course model need be "belongsToMany"? What is the correct syntax for pulling the instructor info? Do i need to specify any foreign key relations in my models?

[image]

Comment: Since the name of your relationship on `$course` model is `instructor()`, you get the instractor like this: `$course->instructor`. As for the days and whether the relationship is set up correctly, we can't know without knowing how the database relations are set up between the two.

Comment: @devk, please check the updated question. I have uploaded a screen shot of my database. the instructor fields with the "1"s in them are referencing the "instructors" table id column.

Comment: `belongsTo` relationship is correct then, but you'll need 4 (1 for each foreign key on the table) of them and you'll need to specify the foreign key name (in the 2nd argument)

Comment: i need to define 4 separate relationships? so public function course1 with hasMany('App\Instructor', 'instructor_day_1') then another relationship of course2 with hasMany('App\Instructor', 'instructor_day_2') etc....?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: wow....can you recommend a more straight forward way of doing that? i was just experimenting with creating an array in my controller or something like that but didn't know where to start exactly. i feel like i may have set this up in a convoluted way. Even if you can suggest a database redesign, i'm interested to know how i can lean this out

Comment: do you have limited number of instructors?

Comment: You might want to have a `many-to-many` relationship instead, but I don't really know your project so it's hard for me to say.

Comment: @ChiragPatel theoretically yes but i have no way to know that limit. I'm sure a school would not have 2000 instructors, but to say they would have 5 or 10 or 8 would be impossible.

Comment: and you need 4 days which have a different date?

Comment: yes. you can see in the screen shot of the database, there are columns for 4 dates and columns for 4 instructor id's.The instructor id's are foreign that relate to the instructors table

Comment: So you can with @devk 's answer. That is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`belongsTo` is the correct relationship, but it's not set up correctly. And you'll need 4 of them, 1 for each foreign key on the `courses` table.

This should get you started:

```
public function instructorDay1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Instructor', 'instructor_day_1');
}
```

And then you would call it like this, to get instructor's name:

```
$course->instructorDay1->name;
```

And you'll need to do this for all 4 relationships.